# Xonix game: detect the proper area

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm working on a Xonix game (like Volfiex) using SFML (graphic library).
The problem is when you cut specific area, the screen splits into two sub areas.
Now I need to detect where the Boss is, and close the OTHER area.

My solution for now is using a matrix as the game board, and determine the area using FloodFill. it's working but I don't like how to player moves because its a matrix and he cant stop between cells.

Maybe you have any better ideas?? (without matrix)
Thanks.

Comment: There always will be some granularity. Maybe you should just increase the resolution of the play grid ? Make it higher than the displayed grid.

Answer (score 0):

Looks very much like [Point inside a polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) problem. I suppose that even if you're drawing curved lines, you still can represent them as a polygon and test ray-segment intersections.